# TF transformation with move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, amcl, move-base, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the code from Learning ROS for robotic programming ([code](https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming_2nd_edition)) .

I am trying to run the code to use the navigation stack in chapter 9.

I first run,

```
roslaunch chapter9_tutorials chapter9_configuration_gazebo.launch
```

and I get this error, but it still brings up Rviz and gazebo

```
WARNING: [/home/nathaniel/Desktop/catkin_ws/src/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming_2nd_edition/chapter9_tutorials/launch/chapter9_configuration_gazebo.launch] unknown <include> attribute 'args'
```

I then run in another terminal this

```
roslaunch chapter9_tutorials move_base.launch
```

and I get the following output and I cannot set nav_goal

```
[ INFO] [1452891660.578951021]: Requesting the map...
[ WARN] [1452891660.579428957]: Request for map failed; trying again...
[ INFO] [1452891660.725584980]: Read a 4000 X 4000 map @ 0.050 m/cell
[ INFO] [1452891661.092120645]: Sending map
[ INFO] [1452891661.116882014]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map @ 0.050 m/pix

[ INFO] [1452891661.287410863]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1452891661.415541021]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[ WARN] [1452891665.706081307]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101058 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891670.765391786]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100715 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891675.810640770]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101084 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891676.518616416]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1452891676.518504 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1452891680.863702773]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101096 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891685.922265047]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100973 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891690.972636769]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100894 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891691.518436760]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1452891691.518333 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1452891696.022488241]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100835 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891701.072917128]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100919 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891706.131551787]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101107 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891706.517966566]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1452891706.517833 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1452891711.185206478]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100958 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891716.241206650]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101173 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891721.296439222]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101055 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891721.518776814]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1452891721.518661 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1452891726.346815147]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101115 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891731.398148683]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101019 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891736.456936463]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101092 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1452891736.518637054]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1452891736.518569 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
```

What is causing this error? I want to use this code for an example for my own robot.

Here is my TF tree

[frames.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14529527968347632.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224242/tf-transformation-with-move_base/) by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2016-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KFBIT](https://answers.ros.org/users/25695/kfbit/) on 2016-01-22**:
ngoldfarb: hello,I am a ros beginner,I am studying this book in chapter 9.I met the same problem with you,but I don't know how to deal with it.Could you tell me how you deal with this question in detail?I will very thankful for your help.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that the problem was in the URDF. it was the wrong `<robotBaseFrame>`It is now working.

---

Originally posted by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) with karma: 127 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-16**:
Glad you figured it out!

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2016-01-23**:
@ngoldfarb , I didn't have to touch the URDF, so I don't think this was the problem.

See https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming_2nd_edition/pull/18

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the first one, `<include>` tag has no attribute as "`args`". Please check [this wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include). Instead, arguments should be supplied like;

```
<include file="included.launch">
  <!-- all vars that included.launch requires must be set -->
  <arg name="hoge" value="fuga" />
</include>
```

For the second one (TF problem), it seems like amcl has different TF configuration. Can you post your TF tree?

**Update**

Looking you TF tree, nobody is publishing a transformation from map to base_footprint. In fact, correct order should be `map->odom->base_footprint`. AMCL may not be running. You can check it with `rosnode list`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-01-16**:
I edited my post to include the TF tree